# How to get 6 Digit Numeric Time in RPG-Free?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am trying to get the system time from my iSeries in a 6 digit numeric format.
The time would be in a `HHMMSS` format.

I have tried using:

```
CDBRVWTM = %Dec(%Time(): *ISO);
```

and

```
CDBRVWTM = %DEC(%CHAR(%TIME()):6:0);
```

The field CDBRVWTM is a 6 digit numeric field in the table.

Comment: And what errors did you get? Which editor and OS version are you using?

Comment: iSeries running V7R2 using Rational Developer For i 9.5

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: Looking back at the errors. It looks like my compiled program was held so it truly wasn't using %dec(%time():*HMS) even though the source said it was. After retrying that line of code and making sure the program compiled, the code ended up working properly.

Comment: Both `CDBRVWTM = %Dec(%Time(): *ISO);` and `CDBRVWTM = %dec(%time():*HMS);` should work as mentioned by Barbara.

Comment: I would expect `CDBRVWTM = %DEC(%CHAR(%TIME()):6:0);` to fail as `%char(%time())` should contain separators that `%dec()` can't process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
**free
ctl-opt main(mainline);


dcl-proc mainline;

   dcl-s CurTime packed(6:0);

   curTime = %dec(%time():*HMS);
   dsply %char(curTime);

   return;

end-proc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Matt, what problem did you have with %Dec(%Time(): *ISO)? That should work fine. Any time format other than *USA should work to get hhmmss.

Comment: Looking back at the errors. It looks like my compiled program was held so it truly wasn't using %dec(%time():*HMS) even though the source said it was. After retrying that line of code and making sure the program compiled, the code ended up working properly.

Answer (score -1):

dcl-s wtime Zoned(6);
wtime= %Dec(%Time()):